# How do you move the first exchange server to another exchange server?

Tags: exchange-migration

I have Exchange 2000 on a Windows 2000 server.  The 2k box is also a root forrest server and domain controller and yes I know that's bad.  This Exchange box was the first one ever installed, upgraded from 5.5.  It has no mailboxes, etc.  All I know is that when I turn off the info store and associated services on that 2k box, the other Exchange servers fail (they start but mail stops delivering ).

How do I get rid of this first Exchange installation?  I have another Exchange 2003 box that is not a domain controller that I want to be the "first" "main" or whatever it is called instead of the old one.

Thank you for any help.  This is my first step in removing the existing domain controller, which is also the root server for our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decommissioning the first Exchange Server:

For Exchange 2000: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307917

For Exchange 2003: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822931/

See this thread for migrating the domain controller roles themselves: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/49afdc39-12b7-414e-9cd8-353fd01b4f31

Comment: Can these be done piece meal or do you have to do it all at once?  For example, can I rehome all the public folders and a few days later do another step?  I'd hate to break it all at once!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can all be done piecemeal - we are currently in the process of doing it ourselves to replace hardware, and we have done it before from an Exchange+DC setup to seperate Exchange and DC servers.  Migrate stuff slowly over a few weeks and no one will even notice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps you have to take to transfer from Exchange 2000 to 2003. [This article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Migrating-Exchange2000-Exchange-2003-Hardware.html) gives a good explanation on the steps you need to take. Because it is the first Exchange 2000 server in your organisation there are some extra steps you need to take, explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307917).